# Javascript image changer: MDN Javascript basics

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm going through the web development guide on the Mozilla Developer Network, and in the [JS basics section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics), I came across this example:

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

myImage.onclick = function() {
    var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    if(mySrc === 'images/firefox-icon.png') {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/firefox2.png');
    } else {
      myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/firefox-icon.png');
    }
}
```

When I worked out this example, although it did execute as expected, I have a question about the image path. Here's my file structure: [image]

My question is: when working with images in html, if the present `.html` file would be in a folder called `pages`, along side with other sibling folders as `images`, `scripts`, etc, the file structure I would have followed in this case to reach an image would be so: `../images/filename.jpg`. The `..` would be used to reach the main(root) folder from the `pages` folder, then access the `images` folder from there.

How does this image changer example work then, without the `..` being used? The file here `main.js` is in a sub-folder of the root.

Comment: File paths are relative to the HTML file, not the script file. In the code above, *images* must be a subdirectory of the directory that the HTML page is in.

Answer (score 0):

> How does this image changer example work then, without the .. being
>   used?

It works because the js file doesn't live alone, it is included in an HTML file, and that HTML file happens to be in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is adding the new image path to the `<img>` node on the html page. All it's doing is inserting some information onto the page, it doesn't know anything about images.

The browser sees that something on the DOM has changed, so it reads the new `src` attribute, downloads the image, and repaints.

As the path is written to the html page, it's relative to where that page is. It doesn't matter that JS inserted it.